# Java 8: Comparator comparingDouble type mismatch

Tags: java, java-8, comparator, java-stream

```
final int[] brr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

for (int i : brr) {
    System.out.println(Math.sin(i));
}

final int leastIdx = Arrays.stream(brr).min(Comparator.comparingDouble(i -> Math.sin(i))).get();
```

leastIdx should be returned as 4 but I can't get this to compile.
Any insights appreciated.

```
The method min() in the type IntStream is not applicable for the 
arguments (Comparator.comparingDouble((<no type> i) -> Math.sin(i)))
```

Answer (score 4):

`IntStream#min` doesn't take a comparator; it just finds the smallest `int` in the stream.  You have to either convert to `Stream<Integer>`:

```
Arrays.stream(brr).boxed()
        .min(comparingDouble(i -> Math.sin(i)))
        .get();
```

or calculate min using `reduce`:

```
Arrays.stream(brr)
        .reduce((x,y) -> Math.sin(x) > Math.sin(y) ? y : x )
        .getAsInt();
```

> leastIdx should be returned as 4

Your stream is actually attempting to find the `int` with the smallest `Math.sin`, not the index of that `int`.  If you want to find the index, you would need to stream over the indexes rather than over the values:

```
int leastIdx = IntStream.range(0, brr.length).boxed()
        .min(comparingDouble(i->Math.sin(brr[i])))
        .get();
```

or, if you are willing to sacrifice clarity to avoid boxing:

```
int leastIdx = IntStream.range(0, brr.length)
        .reduce((x,y) -> Math.sin(brr[x]) > Math.sin(brr[y]) ? y : x)
        .getAsInt();
```

Answer (score 2):

The proposed solutions have a flaw: they calculate the sine two times for almost every element. Thus for 1000 input elements you will have to calculate sine about 2000 times.

There are two solutions involving my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library which calculate the sine exactly once per stream element:

```
final int leastIdx = IntStreamEx
        .ofIndices(brr).boxed()
        .minByDouble(i -> Math.sin(brr[i])).get();
```

Or alternatively:

```
final int leastIdx = (int) IntStreamEx.of(brr)
        .mapToObj(Math::sin)
        .collect(MoreCollectors.minIndex()).getAsLong();
```

Both return 4 on your input. Unfortunately currently both of them involve boxing. Currently StreamEx does not provide a way to eliminate both boxing and twice sine calculation.

Comment: I wouldn’t care unless a profiler tells me that calculating `sin` twice is a problem. It’s not too unlikely that it gets optimized away.

Comment: @Holger, probably sine is not so big problem, but in some cases it could be significant depending on the particular key extractor function.